# JS - how to replace an object with spread operator AND condtion?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects.
I need to:

- check if the object has a specific key:value combination
- if yes, replace a different value of this object
- return both the objects

This is how I am trying to achieve it:

```
list.map(item => {
          return {
            ...item,
            ...(item["orderId"] === 'xyz' && { transactionNumber: 'sadfdas gasdgas' }),
          }
```

I also tried this condition instead:

```
...(orderId === 'xyz' && { transactionNumber: 'sadfdas gasdgas' })
```

and this:

```
...(item.orderId === 'xyz' && { transactionNumber: 'sadfdas gasdgas' })
```

and this:

```
...(item.orderId === 'xyz' ? { transactionNumber: 'sadfdas gasdgas' } : {})
```

However they all return the two objects in the list unchanged.

If I instead use this code:

```
.map(item => {
  return {
    ...item,
  transactionNumber: 'sadfdasgasdgas' 
  }
})
```

it replaces the `transactionNumber` for each object.

What am I doing wrong that the condition is not working?

Example of what should happen:

```
const list = [{
aaa: 123,
bbb: 222,
orderId: 555,
transactionNumber: 888
},
aaa: 123,
bbb: 222,
orderId: 555,
transactionNumber:999
]
```

If we process the variable above, the result would be:

```
[{
aaa: 123,
bbb: 222,
orderId: 555,
transactionNumber: 888
},
aaa: 123,
bbb: 222,
orderId: 555,
transactionNumber:999
]
```

But if we process the following array:

```
[{
aaa: 123,
bbb: 222,
orderId: "xyz",
transactionNumber: 888
},
aaa: 123,
bbb: 222,
orderId: 555,
transactionNumber:"sadfdasgasdgas"
]
```

the result should be:

```
[{
aaa: 123,
bbb: 222,
orderId: "xyz",
transactionNumber: 888
},
aaa: 123,
bbb: 222,
orderId: 555,
transactionNumber:999
]
```

Comment: `...(item.orderId === 'xyz' ? { transactionNumber: 'sadfdas gasdgas' } : {})`

Comment: still the same, returns the two objects unchanged

Comment: Please give an example of what data you have and what you expect as an output.

Comment: Where did 999 come in the second example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a ternary operator as follows:

```js
const list = [ { orderId: "xyz", transactionNumber: "1" }, { orderId: "abc", transactionNumber: "2" } ];

const res = list.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  transactionNumber: item["orderId"] === 'xyz' ? 'sadfdas gasdgas' : item["transactionNumber"]
}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This would add `transactionNumber: undefined` to objects that don't have it.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie OP didn't mention that it's an optional property, this approach is better than creating an object

Comment: this one changes two values. I need to change one 1 value, based on the condition if the same object has a specific key:value

Comment: All the object values are present. There are no optional key/values

Comment: @Pikk what do you mean change two values? it changes the first item since it's matching the condition

Comment: @MajedBadawi I put an example of what I need in the original question

Comment: @MajedBadawi there was a spelling mistake from my side, that's why it didn't work. Assigning you the best answer, as it came first and it uses the condition I wanted/tried to do in the original question, without copying the object.

Answer (score 1):

Either return an updated object if the condition matches, or return the object if it doesn't.

```js
const list = [
  { name: 1, orderId: 'abc', transactionNumber: 1 },
  { name: 2, orderId: 'xyz', transactionNumber: 2 },
  { name: 3, orderId: 'efg', transactionNumber: 3 }
];

// Make a copy of the object "in transit"
const out = list.map(({ ...item }) => {

  // Update the number of the object if
  // the condition is true
  if (item.orderId === 'xyz') {
    item.transactionNumber = 'test';
  }
  
  // Return the item
  return item;

});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: This copies the reference of objects not matching the condition